# How can I import another JS file (which is in the same directory) in a electron JS file

Tags: javascript, html, css, import, electron

I'd like to import "new.js" inside "main.js", using  `const new = require("new.js")`, i tried also `import "./new.js"`, but I doesn't want to work.

This is my code if you want to see it

```
// Modules to control application life and create native browser window
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const path = require('path')

function createWindow() {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadFile('index.htm')

  // Open the DevTools.
  // mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()

  app.on('activate', function () {
    // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
    // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
  })
})

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  // On macOS it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})
// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.
//password
```

i hope you can help me, please do NOT judge my coding skills, i am still learning.
Anyway here there is my html and css code too.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <!-- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP -->
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">
  <meta http-equiv="X-Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>FYco</title>
</head>

<body>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <h1>FYco app</h1>
  <form id="whoAreyou">
    <label for="whoAreyou">
      Chi sei?
    </label>
    <br>
    <select>
      <option value="1">Federico Santucci</option>
      <option value="2">Yuri de Marco</option>
      <option value="3">Simone Stroppiana</option>
      <option value="4">Edoardo Casali</option>
      <option value="5">Guido Betti</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <br>
    <div id="password">
      <input id="password" type="password">
    </div>
    <form id="send">
      <input id="send" type="submit">
    </form>
  </form>
  <!-- You can also require other files to run in this process -->
  <script src="./renderer.js"></script>
  <script src="new.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #333;
}

select {
    text-align: center;
    border: 3px solid #555;
    width: 25em; height: 3em;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-style: italic;
}

h1 {
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 48px;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}

label {
    text-align: center;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 48px;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-style: italic;
}

input[type=password] {
    border: 3px solid #555;
    width: 25em; height: 3em;
}

input[type=submit] {
    border: 3px solid #555;
    width: 25em; height: 3em;
}
/* IDs */
#password {text-align: center}
#whoAreyou{text-align: center}
/*
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
*/
```

I hope everything of my code is clear to you.

Comment: sorry if I forgot to tell you what there is inside the "./new.js" file. Anyway here it is. ```function main_App() {
    if (document.getElementById('password') === "Burgman1!") {
        alert("You got the right password");
        location.href = "./new.htm";
    }
}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to see the content of your `new.js` file and how you're exporting the module first.

Ensure you're exporting the content you need using `module.exports`

For example

new.js

```
const newObj = { a: 5, b:6 };
module.exports = newObj;
```

main.js

```
const importedObj = require('./new.js');
console.log(importedObj);
// will output { a: 5, b:6 }
```

Comment: Ok... it worked, but it doesn't do what it should, as you can see it should make a ```onClick``` event, opening another .html file, but it doesn't, is it right to use ```location.href``` to make it?

Comment: That might work. But `location.href` sets the browser's URL path so instead of `./new.htm` like you would do if you were importing in js, you would just use `/new.htm`